# How to draw Quadratic Bezier Curves in Stage 3d? Would I need to break them to segments?

Tags: actionscript-3, bezier, stage3d

I am currently using the native .curveTo function and wondering if I could write some code that will render Quadratic Bezier Curves in Stage3D? I also may need to perform fills between the curves I draw to the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Fills are supported by the extension

https://github.com/unwrong/Starling-Extension-Graphics/blob/master/extension/src/starling/display/graphics/Fill.as

It uses a triangulator under the hood to process the fill into something the GPU can handle.

Answer (score 1):

It has already been implemented for Starling. Hope you'll find it useful:
https://github.com/unwrong/Starling-Extension-Graphics/pull/1

Comment: Does that support fills as well? Thanks.

Comment: After reading it, it seems it does not support the fill part. I wonder if that is something that could be achieved with a reasonable amount of effort.